# Having trouble with a Javascript adding system (simple but I'm slow)

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to make a program here where I press a button and once its pressed I input a number (from 1-3) and then it outputs the inputted value.

Then you can press the button again and add another value (again from 1-3) and it adds the second input to the first input and so on.

This is the code I've got so far and it doesn't work, it just outputs my inputted value and that's it. Nothing gets added and updated.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
        function addone() 
        {
             x=parseInt(prompt("What goal importance did you complete?"));
                var sum = 0;             

              if (x === 1) 
              {
               sum = sum + x;
              }
              else if (x=== 2)
              {
                sum = sum + x;
              }
        else if (x=== 3)
              {
                sum = sum + x;
              }

              
              document.getElementById("myBtn").innerHTML = x;
        }
    </script>
```

The button and the ouput are with:

`<button  onclick="addone()">Coins</button>`
`<h1>Coins:</h1>`
`<h4 id='myBtn'>0</h4>`

Comment: You set `sum` to 0 every time you call the function, what did you expect?

Comment: @Aplet123 I set it to `var sum;` but I guess there is no way for the code to remember what the previous input was (eg. 2). Which means it cannot add to that value, it keeps resetting

Comment: Put the sum variable outside of the function.

Comment: @Aplet123 Still nothing :( `var sum;
  function addone()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Aplet123, each time you execute the `addOne` function, you restart the `sum` as 0.
The simplest way is to initialize it outside the function.

By the way, there is no need for the elseif conditions in your code, regarding the feature you want to achieve, the best, for readability should be to use a AND condition :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var sum = 0;
        function addone() 
        {
             x=parseInt(prompt("What goal importance did you complete?"));

              if (x >= 1 && x <=3) 
              {
               sum = sum + x;
              }

              
              document.getElementById("myBtn").innerHTML = sum;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you my friend!

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix one thing before moving on. You are instantiating the `sum` as 0 whenever you run the function. To fix this, declare the `sum` outside of the function. You can reset it if you want later in the program if you like.

Next, you want to accept only 1, 2 or 3 as the input. You can shorten the `if else` condition so that it checks that input is more than or equal to 1, but less than or equal to 3.

Finally - You are adding the values of input to the `sum` variable. The variable `x` is not changing itself. So, you will always see the number you input. Change the `innerhtml` value to `sum`.

**EDIT** - I have also included comments in the code below -

```
var sum = 0; //Declare sum outside the function
function addone(){
    let x=parseInt(prompt("What goal importance did you complete?"));
    
    if (x >= 1 && x <=3){ //Shorten the if else condition
        sum += x;
    }
    
    document.getElementById("myBtn").innerHTML = sum; //Display the sum
}
```

Comment: it should be ```x>=1 && x<=3```

Comment: @clod9353 sorry it's a mistake. I will correct it.

Comment: @clod9353 I have corrected it. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.